# My minecraft 1.10 crashes (On multiplayer)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

All's normal when a launch, but when I join a multiplayer (Ex:*hypixel*)
A few moments after joining my game crashes. Here's a crash report I can't make sense out of. (No mods on my MC)

```
--- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't do that.

Time: 6/22/16 2:12 PM
Description: Server forgot to send required information to construct BlockEntity

java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing BlockEntity
at bqy.b(SourceFile:162)
at bqu.a(SourceFile:100)
at bqu.run(SourceFile:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- BlockEntity missing instance data --
Details:
BlockState: minecraft:end_portal
Block coordinates: World: (-2598,50,728), Chunk: (at 10,3,8 in -163,45; contains blocks -2608,0,720 to -2593,255,735), Region: (-6,1; contains chunks -192,32 to -161,63, blocks -3072,0,512 to -2561,255,1023)

-- Affected level --
Details:
Level name: MpServer
All players: 18 total; [bnn['YummyBakedPie'/10579, l='MpServer', x=-2560.15, y=54.00, z=739.30], bno['jm8160'/10275, l='MpServer', x=-2561.56, y=54.00, z=745.91], bno['loonewolf'/10152, l='MpServer', x=-2562.53, y=54.00, z=744.00], bno['Haztrak'/10411, l='MpServer', x=-2561.69, y=54.00, z=743.00], bno['PenetrujacyMajo'/10454, l='MpServer', x=-2561.88, y=54.00, z=745.72], bno['Scherzyy'/10465, l='MpServer', x=-2561.03, y=54.00, z=744.25], bno['Ria_Roo'/10477, l='MpServer', x=-2562.78, y=54.00, z=743.56], bno['EmiliaChewie'/10155, l='MpServer', x=-2542.97, y=52.00, z=733.03], bno['VladK123'/10482, l='MpServer', x=-2534.13, y=52.00, z=728.91], bno['Kilde'/10563, l='MpServer', x=-2542.20, y=52.00, z=736.56], bno['MegaWallsChamp'/10440, l='MpServer', x=-2544.78, y=52.00, z=738.47], bno['OmgItsIlse'/10451, l='MpServer', x=-2536.38, y=52.00, z=753.50], bno['Duttat'/10601, l='MpServer', x=-2557.51, y=53.52, z=745.20], bno['Kirrific'/10605, l='MpServer', x=-2562.45, y=54.00, z=743.49], bno['cutebunny60'/10608, l='MpServer', x=-2563.53, y=54.00, z=743.69], bno['MSkyX'/10531, l='MpServer', x=-2530.63, y=53.09, z=744.34], bno['d6nnwepik1'/126, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=720.50], bno['d6w4kvqfoy'/130, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=768.50]]
Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 169, 169
Level seed: 0
Level generator: ID 01 - flat, ver 0. Features enabled: false
Level generator options: 
Level spawn location: World: (-2564,54,743), Chunk: (at 12,3,7 in -161,46; contains blocks -2576,0,736 to -2561,255,751), Region: (-6,1; contains chunks -192,32 to -161,63, blocks -3072,0,512 to -2561,255,1023)
Level time: 1146012421 game time, 111000 day time
Level dimension: 0
Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
Forced entities: 63 total; [bnn['YummyBakedPie'/10579, l='MpServer', x=-2560.20, y=54.00, z=739.30], xx['§e§lRIGHT CLICK§r'/128, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=51.97, z=720.50], bno['jm8160'/10275, l='MpServer', x=-2561.56, y=54.00, z=745.91], xx['§bThe Delivery Man§r'/129, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.25, z=720.50], bno['MSkyX'/10531, l='MpServer', x=-2529.69, y=52.00, z=725.81], bno['d6w4kvqfoy'/130, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=768.50], bno['MC_Legend21'/10104, l='MpServer', x=-2561.28, y=54.00, z=744.03], bno['koneni321'/10143, l='MpServer', x=-2561.59, y=54.00, z=745.47], xx['§e§lRIGHT CLICK§r'/132, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=51.97, z=768.50], bno['loonewolf'/10152, l='MpServer', x=-2562.53, y=54.00, z=744.00], xx['§bThe Delivery Man§r'/133, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.25, z=768.50], bno['Haztrak'/10411, l='MpServer', x=-2561.69, y=54.00, z=743.00], xx['§bMystery Vault'/134, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.38, z=736.50], bno['PenetrujacyMajo'/10454, l='MpServer', x=-2561.88, y=54.00, z=745.72], xx['§e§lRIGHT CLICK'/135, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.09, z=736.50], bno['Scherzyy'/10465, l='MpServer', x=-2561.03, y=54.00, z=744.25], zn['Villager'/136, l='MpServer', x=-2556.50, y=53.00, z=749.50], bno['Ria_Roo'/10477, l='MpServer', x=-2562.78, y=54.00, z=743.56], xx['§e§lRIGHT CLICK§r'/137, l='MpServer', x=-2556.50, y=53.16, z=749.50], xx['§bQuest Master§r'/138, l='MpServer', x=-2556.50, y=53.47, z=749.50], wa['Bat'/139, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=53.35, z=720.50], wa['Bat'/140, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=53.35, z=768.50], bno['MasonH04'/9942, l='MpServer', x=-2532.56, y=52.75, z=733.97], bno['EmiliaChewie'/10155, l='MpServer', x=-2542.97, y=52.00, z=733.03], bno['VladK123'/10482, l='MpServer', x=-2534.13, y=52.00, z=728.91], bno['Kilde'/10563, l='MpServer', x=-2542.16, y=52.00, z=736.56], bno['KaneCraft'/10575, l='MpServer', x=-2542.66, y=52.00, z=737.06], bno['Kirrific'/10605, l='MpServer', x=-2562.16, y=54.00, z=743.22], bno['MegaWallsChamp'/10440, l='MpServer', x=-2544.78, y=52.00, z=738.47], bno['DragonPuppie101'/10534, l='MpServer', x=-2542.84, y=52.47, z=747.69], bno['cutebunny60'/10608, l='MpServer', x=-2563.53, y=54.00, z=743.69], bno['MSkyX'/10531, l='MpServer', x=-2530.63, y=53.17, z=744.58], bno['OmgItsIlse'/10451, l='MpServer', x=-2536.38, y=52.00, z=753.50], bno['d6nnwepik1'/126, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=720.50], bno['d6w4kvqfoy'/130, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=768.50], bno['MasonH04'/9942, l='MpServer', x=-2530.03, y=52.00, z=724.31], bno['deerclowm'/10584, l='MpServer', x=-2559.03, y=53.50, z=749.31], bno['jm8160'/10275, l='MpServer', x=-2561.56, y=54.00, z=745.91], bno['MSkyX'/10531, l='MpServer', x=-2530.63, y=53.17, z=744.58], bno['loonewolf'/10152, l='MpServer', x=-2562.53, y=54.00, z=744.00], bno['Haztrak'/10411, l='MpServer', x=-2561.69, y=54.00, z=743.00], bno['EmiliaChewie'/10155, l='MpServer', x=-2542.97, y=52.00, z=733.03], bno['VickyT'/10589, l='MpServer', x=-2542.84, y=52.00, z=739.75], bno['Kilde'/10563, l='MpServer', x=-2542.16, y=52.00, z=736.56], bno['MegaWallsChamp'/10440, l='MpServer', x=-2544.78, y=52.00, z=738.47], bno['OmgItsIlse'/10451, l='MpServer', x=-2536.38, y=52.00, z=753.50], xx['§c7 Deliveries!§r'/10580, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.56, z=720.50], xx['§c7 Deliveries!§r'/10581, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.56, z=768.50], bno['PenetrujacyMajo'/10454, l='MpServer', x=-2561.88, y=54.00, z=745.72], xx['§c2 Available!§r'/10582, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.69, z=736.50], xx['§c2 Available!§r'/10583, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.69, z=752.50], bno['Duttat'/10601, l='MpServer', x=-2557.67, y=53.68, z=745.30], bno['Scherzyy'/10465, l='MpServer', x=-2561.03, y=54.00, z=744.25], xx['Armor Stand'/10600, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=54.69, z=752.50], bno['Duttat'/10601, l='MpServer', x=-2557.67, y=53.68, z=745.30], bno['Ria_Roo'/10477, l='MpServer', x=-2562.78, y=54.00, z=743.56], bno['Kirrific'/10605, l='MpServer', x=-2562.16, y=54.00, z=743.22], bno['cutebunny60'/10608, l='MpServer', x=-2563.53, y=54.00, z=743.69], bno['VladK123'/10482, l='MpServer', x=-2534.13, y=52.00, z=728.91], xx['§5Epic Solar Power Suit Chestpiece'/10611, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.69, z=752.50], xx['§bMystery Vault'/124, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.38, z=752.50], xx['§e§lRIGHT CLICK'/125, l='MpServer', x=-2538.50, y=52.09, z=752.50], bno['d6nnwepik1'/126, l='MpServer', x=-2530.50, y=52.00, z=720.50]]
Retry entities: 0 total; []
Server brand: BungeeCord (Hypixel) <- vanilla
Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
at bln.a(SourceFile:364)
at bcx.b(SourceFile:2535)
at bqu.run(SourceFile:49)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.10.1
Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
Launched Version: 1.10.1
LWJGL: 2.9.4
OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

Using VBOs: No
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
Type: Client (map_client.txt)
Resource Packs: Quadral v.2.2 MC1.10.zip
Current Language: English (US)
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Comment: Based on the other question in the comments, you probably want to roll back to 1.10 from 1.10.1 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Load into minecraft 1.10 instead of 1.10.1 and it should fix the problem.